# VBA code to change size of one slide only in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

how can I change the size of one slide in a presentation using VBA?

I know the `PageSetup.SlideWidth` and `PageSetup.SlideHeight` properties, but these work on the presentation and as a result on all slides.

I'm sure this is possible, since you can do this manually in powerpoint.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: how do you do that in PP application?

Comment: If you can explain how you do this manually, perhaps we can tell you how to reproduce programmatically - but like @KazJaw and Steve Rindsberg, at first glance I'd say "it's not possible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Not under program control, not manually.